# Installing haskell's cabal or ghcup inside a dockerfile wont work

Tags: docker, haskell

This is my dockerfile for haskell:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential curl \
libffi-dev libffi7 libgmp-dev libgmp10 \
libncurses-dev libncurses5 libtinfo5

ENV BOOTSTRAP_HASKELL_NONINTERACTIVE=1

RUN sh -c "curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh"
RUN sh -c "curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh"
```

even though it install ghcup I cannot run `cabal` neither `ghcup`.

What is wrong?

Even running this inside the docker container in bash will say

```
[ Warn  ] Cabal ver 3.4.0.0 already installed; if you really want to reinstall it, you may want to run 'ghcup rm cabal 3.4.0.0' first
```

but I cannot launch cabal or ghcup.

Comment: what error do you get running which script/lines?

Answer (score 10):

ghcup maintainer here.

I recommend to use ghcup as follows in Docker, which will not require messing with PATH:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin

# install dependencies
RUN \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
        libnuma-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libgmp-dev \
        libgmp10 \
        git \
        wget \
        lsb-release \
        software-properties-common \
        gnupg2 \
        apt-transport-https \
        gcc \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        build-essential

# install gpg keys
ARG GPG_KEY=7784930957807690A66EBDBE3786C5262ECB4A3F
RUN gpg --batch --keyserver keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys $GPG_KEY

# install ghcup
RUN \
    curl https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghcup/x86_64-linux-ghcup > /usr/bin/ghcup && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/ghcup && \
    ghcup config set gpg-setting GPGStrict

ARG GHC=8.10.7
ARG CABAL=latest

# install GHC and cabal
RUN \
    ghcup -v install ghc --isolate /usr/local --force ${GHC} && \
    ghcup -v install cabal --isolate /usr/local/bin --force ${CABAL}
```

You can read about isolated installations [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/guide/#isolated-installs).

Answer (score 4):

You have to include their paths to `PATH` in order to be discoverable.
In addition, I prefer to use `bash` instead of `sh`.

This one is working as expected and note the two different ways to declare ENV variables as also some common commands:

```dockerfile
FROM debian:stable-slim as build

# Install dependencies *You don't need all of them
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y git jq bc make automake libnuma-dev \
    && apt-get install -y rsync htop curl build-essential \
    && apt-get install -y pkg-config libffi-dev libgmp-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libssl-dev libtinfo-dev libsystemd-dev \
    && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev make g++ wget libncursesw5 libtool autoconf \
    && apt-get clean

# Install ghcup
ENV BOOTSTRAP_HASKELL_NONINTERACTIVE=1
RUN bash -c "curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh"
RUN bash -c "curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh"

# Add ghcup to PATH
ENV PATH=${PATH}:/root/.local/bin
ENV PATH=${PATH}:/root/.ghcup/bin

# Install cabal
RUN bash -c "ghcup upgrade"
RUN bash -c "ghcup install cabal 3.4.0.0"
RUN bash -c "ghcup set cabal 3.4.0.0"

# Install GHC
RUN bash -c "ghcup install ghc 8.10.4"
RUN bash -c "ghcup set ghc 8.10.4"

# Update Path to include Cabal and GHC exports
RUN bash -c "echo PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" >> $HOME/.bashrc"
RUN bash -c "echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> $HOME/.bashrc"
RUN bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc"

# Update cabal
RUN bash -c "cabal update"
```

Comment: this looks like it would work. I had a similar issue on my ubuntu container. manually adding the paths worked for me, but in the future I'll add it to my Dockerfile as in your example. thanks.

Comment: You have no idea how much you've helped me. Thanks a lot!