# How can I develop in Haskell with a docker image with .devcontainer?

Tags: docker, haskell, vscode-devcontainer

I want to use .devcontainer so my teammembers can have an identical setup. I cannot get this to work. This is how the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
## Inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680726/installing-haskells-cabal-or-ghcup-inside-a-dockerfile-wont-work
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin
ARG USERNAME=vscode


ENV USERNAME=${USERNAME} \
    USER_UID=1000 \
    USER_GID=1000 \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    LANG=C.UTF8 \
    WDIR=/home/${USERNAME}


# install dependencies
RUN \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    libnuma-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libgmp10 \
    git \
    wget \
    lsb-release \
    software-properties-common \
    gnupg2 \
    apt-transport-https \
    gcc \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    build-essential

# install gpg keys
ARG GPG_KEY=BA3CBA3FFE22B574
RUN gpg --batch --keyserver keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys $GPG_KEY

# install ghcup
RUN \
    curl https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghcup/x86_64-linux-ghcup > /usr/bin/ghcup && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/ghcup && \
    ghcup config set gpg-setting GPGLax


ARG GHC=8.10.7
ARG CABAL=3.10.1.0
ARG HLS=2.0.0.1
ARG STACK=2.11.1

# install GHC and cabal

RUN ghcup -v install ghc --isolate /usr/local --force ${GHC}
RUN ghcup -v install cabal --isolate /usr/local/bin --force ${CABAL}
RUN ghcup -v install stack --isolate /usr/local/bin --force ${STACK}
RUN ghcup -v install hls --isolate /usr/local/bin --force ${HLS}

RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME && \
    useradd -ms /bin/bash -K MAIL_DIR=/dev/null --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME && \
    mkdir -p /etc/sudoers.d && \
    echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME

USER ${USER_UID}:${USER_GID}

WORKDIR ${WDIR}

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=dialog

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be something wrong with the paths: the Haskell extentions gives the following output:

```
2023-07-29 05:28:48.3350000 [client] ERROR Error executing 'ghcup --no-verbose whereis hls 2.0.0.1' with error code 30
2023-07-29 05:28:48.3350000 [client] ERROR stderr: [1m[ Error ][0m []8;;https://errors.haskell.org/messages/GHCup-00130\GHCup-00130]8;;\] The version 2.0.0.1 of the tool hls is not installed.

2023-07-29 05:28:48.3520000 [client] ERROR Error executing 'ghcup --no-verbose whereis cabal 3.10.1.0' with error code 30
2023-07-29 05:28:48.3520000 [client] ERROR stderr: [1m[ Error ][0m []8;;https://errors.haskell.org/messages/GHCup-00130\GHCup-00130]8;;\] The version 3.10.1.0 of the tool cabal is not installed.

2023-07-29 05:28:48.3690000 [client] ERROR Error executing 'ghcup --no-verbose whereis stack 2.11.1' with error code 30
2023-07-29 05:28:48.3690000 [client] ERROR stderr: [1m[ Error ][0m []8;;https://errors.haskell.org/messages/GHCup-00130\GHCup-00130]8;;\] The version 2.11.1 of the tool stack is not installed.
```

If I open a terminal in vscode, I can see that everything is installed properly, and it is in my path:

```
vscode@c983ad0b50ef:/workspaces/Ampersand$ which stack
/usr/local/bin/stack
vscode@c983ad0b50ef:/workspaces/Ampersand$ whoami
vscode
vscode@c983ad0b50ef:/workspaces/Ampersand$ echo $PATH
/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/bin/remote-cli:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
vscode@c983ad0b50ef:/workspaces/Ampersand$
```

I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I haven't seriously played with Haskell in a while, but can you use something like [The Haskell Tool Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/) to get a consistent environment, including consistent versions of the toolchain, without needing to work around Docker's isolation features?

Comment: @DavidMaze : The point is I want to leverage the power of .devcontainer, so all other teammembers don't have to worry at all about their toolstack. That's the whole point of this question.

Comment: There's not enough interest to maintain a devcontainer in the community, unfortunately. Check out a recent discussion about having an official devcontainer: https://github.com/haskell/meta/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the problem with your specific setup is, but you could also use [devcontainer features](https://containers.dev/implementors/features/) without having to build your own Docker image.  There is a [devcontainer feature](https://github.com/devcontainers-contrib/features/tree/main/src/haskell) which you can use to install Haskell.  You should also be able to configure [environment variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/environment-variables) in `devcontainer.json`.

I have such a [setup](https://github.com/chungyc/ninetynine/blob/main/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json) myself to set up a GitHub Codespace.